# A simple syntax does not work

Tags: numerics, machine-precision

The code below does not work. Can anyone tell me why? Thanks!

```
 For[t = -1, t <= 1, t = t + 0.01, 
 For[z = -1, z <= 1, z = z + 0.01, If[t*z == 0, Print[t, ", ", z]]]]
```

Answer (score 4):

It's the result of error accumulation of float number:

```
Nest[# + 0.01 &, -1, 100]
% == 0
(* 7.5287*10^-16 *)
(* False *)
```

There're many ways to fix this, for example, using arbitrary-precision number. In your case a `Precision` of `1.` is enough:

```
0.01`1 // Precision
Nest[# + 0.01`1 &, -1, 100]
% == 0
(* 1. *)
(* 0.*10^-1 *)
(* True *)
```

Or simply use exact number:

```
Nest[# + 1/100 &, -1, 100]
% == 0
(* 0 *)
(* True *)
```

Comment: What if I have a function gives numerical values, for example, if I have something like f(0.01,0.02)=0.2312, and I want to check if f(a,b)==0, how should I do this?

Comment: @lol This depends on the structure of the function